# PHP: Blob from database in tmpfile() - rewind (or fseek) don't work

Tags: php, imagemagick, temporary-files

I have to use ImageMagick-6.3.5, so in order to work around the bug with readimageblob and pdf, I use tmpfile().

I want to have a preview of the first page of pdf.
I use rewind() to be at the first page, but it still gives me the preview of the last page...

What can I do to get the preview of the first page?

Installing newer version of ImageMagick isn't an option.

I tried to do $img->readimagefile($temp."[0]"), but it doesn't work either.

Here is my code:

```
$image = Doctrine::getTable('Images')->find($id)
$img = new Imagick();
$temp = tmpfile();
fwrite($temp, $image->image);
rewind($temp);
$img->readimagefile($temp);
fclose($temp);
$img->setResolution(300,300);
$img->resizeImage($width,$height,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,0);
$img->setImageFormat('png');
$img->writeImage ($url);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to this:
we can use: $img->setIteratorIndex(0)

The following code works:

```
$image = Doctrine::getTable('Images')->find($id)
$img = new Imagick();
$temp = tmpfile();
fwrite($temp, $image->image);
rewind($temp);
$img->readimagefile($temp);
fclose($temp);
$img->setResolution(300,300);
$img->setIteratorIndex(0);
$img->resizeImage($width,$height,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,0);
$img->setImageFormat('png');
$img->writeImage ($url);
```

Answer (score 2):

ImageMagick doesn't directly read pdf's - it uses Ghostscript to do it. So instead of relying on this, do the conversion yourself, use the `pdftoppm` program, and pass it the appropriate -f and -l numbers.

You can keep using "invisible" temporary files and use `proc_open()`. Have one temp file for input, and the other for output.

Or save the file with an actual name, generate a second name (use `tempnam()` for both) then `exec` pdftoppm with that name and the output file name. Then have ImageMagick read that file by name instead of handle (be sure to delete them after).

Either way you'll need two temporary files. I would prefer proc_open since you don't have to worry about deleting files, or lost files if there was a crash. But it's slightly more complex to use (not much).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I found out simpler solution.